# Reverse Inequality Geometric Representation

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

For the triangle inequality there is a straightforward representation which is that the length of the hypotenuse is smaller from the sum of both sides.

Is there a geometric explanation for the reverse inequality?

Comment: By "reverse inequality" do you mean "in a triangle a side is greater than the difference of the other two sides"?

Comment: $d(x,z)-d(y,z)\leq d(x,y)$